# Equivalent JSONP for Python3

Tags: jquery, python, jsonp

I see a part of code on internet who use jsonp to make a request like this:

```
new Request.JSONP({
    url: "url",
    data: {
        params: JSON.encode({
            data: login
        })
    },
}).send()
```

And I would like ot know if it exist an equivalent of this jsonp in python. It's not a POST or GET method.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, it is a GET. JSONP is not a different method, it's simply a way of providing a callback to get around the browser same-origin policy. As such it makes no sense to ask about doing it in Python.

Comment: Knowledge. Thanks for ur help.